# What are the differences in difficulty modes?

Tags: final-fantasy-15

There are 2 difficulty levels in the options menu: Normal (default) and Easy.

What are the differences between the 2 modes?

To help reduce the scope, I am personally interested in things like:

- Battle difficulty
- EXP earned
- Miss-able trophies (based on difficulty)

Basically, what will I lose out on (other then the challenge) of playing on Easy mode?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For combat differences:

According to the [Wikia](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Difficulty_level), Easy Mode will make enemies weaker and have Carbuncle prevent you from dying numerous times before you *actually* die.

> Final Fantasy XV also has a standard difficulty and easy mode. The player can change difficulty at any time. The easy mode is made so that one can generally win by just button mashing. In the easy mode, Carbuncle can appear to heal Noctis if he is in danger of dying.

Note that you *can* still die on Easy mode. See [this thread](https://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/932981-final-fantasy-xv/74642313):

> Many will tell you it's impossible to die in easy mode but that simply is not true. It's tougher due to Carbuncle reviving you a ton of times, but i've tested this, and you can still die in easy mode because he will stop reviving you eventually.
>
> I went up against an Iron Giant on easy and still died after only being revived a good 3-5 times. After that, Carbuncle just stopped showing up which led to a game over.

Lastly, it appears that you can extend the amount of time you can spend in Wait Mode if you are playing on the Easy difficulty. See [here](http://www.itechpost.com/articles/61480/20161203/final-fantasy-xv-guide-wait-mode-when-activate-works.htm):

> If you want to have a longer wait mode, you can always toggle the difficulty settings. To do this, enter the pause menu, select Difficulty, then switch to easy. With a lower difficulty setting, enemies are weaker and the wait mode is extended, giving you a longer time to rehash your decisions.

---

As for trophies, there is a single missable trophy if you play on Easy Mode. From [this list](http://psnprofiles.com/trophies/5612-FINAL-FANTASY-XV):

> [Chosen King](http://finalfantasyxv.gamepedia.com/Chosen_King): Defeated Ifrit on Normal difficulty.

Though, I've read that you can switch the difficulty to Normal just before the fight and still get the trophy.

---

Finally, for your question about EXP or items rewarded, I can't find any evidence of the drop rates/amounts being any different across difficulties. From the same thread as earlier:

> As far as I know, yes. But I wasn't really counting the EXP when doing my Carbuncle tests on easy.

Comment: Awesome, that pretty much covers all of my concerns. Time to switch to easy until that trophy then... after 22 hours of play time, the battle system just isn't fun enough to justify the difficulty challenge unfortunately.

Comment: If only Easy mode sped up how long it takes to level up my Survival skill...

Comment: ah yes, I remember you from reading the Gladiolus question now... personally I thought it was based on how much collect from loot rather than walking, but I can't remember why I though that...

Comment: @musefan yeah Gladiolus picks up more/better loot with a higher skill. Why the strength of his calves directly improves his eyesight is beyond me

Comment: it's entirely possible to level up Gladiolus' survival by having Noctis run around in circles at Galdin Quay (or a similar safe outpost) for an extended period of time and If you use a rubber band (or similar) to keep the analogue sticks together then you can leave the game running while you go have dinner or go to work etc..

Comment: @NeilHibbert I will definitely try this once I finish up Steins;Gate 0! Thank you for the tip!